# How to hide the tab bar with animation in iOS 13?

Tags: animation, show-hide, uitabbar, ios13, cgaffinetransform

**In my tabBarController, I use these two methods to hide/show the tabBar:**

```
func showTabBar() {
    tabBar.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.tabBar.transform = .identity
    }
}

func hideTabBar() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.tabBar.frame.height)
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    })
}
```

This has worked well in iOS 12 and below, but in iOS 13, when the transforms are applied, the whole tabBar is broken (see picture). I know that you can hide the tabBar with frame animations, but applying transforms is much easier and I don't understand why this is broken and **what changed in iOS 13 that prevents this from working**.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem...

Comment: @benjamin not yet. Apparently, you can't use transforms on the iOS 13 tab bar. You have 2 choices: either implement it with frame animations or use the built in hidesBottomBarWhenPushed functionality.

Comment: Ok thank you. I sent a message to Apple with their Feedback Assistant. I hope they will help us...

Answer (score 4):

'transform' property of tabbar is not working in iOS 13 for now, maybe it'll work later.

while hiding tabbar you just need to hold the last frame of your tabbar.

To show tabbar: -

```
func showTabbar(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController?, _ lastTabBarFrame: CGRect?) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = lastTabBarFrame ?? .zero
        }, completion: { (_) in
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tabBarController?.tabBar.transform = .identity
        }, completion: { (_) in
        })
    }
}
```

To hide tabbar: -

```
func hideTabbar(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController?, _ lastTabBarFrame: CGRect?, _ view: UIView) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height + (lastTabBarFrame?.height ?? 0.0) + 20, width: lastTabBarFrame?.width ?? 0.0, height: lastTabBarFrame?.height ?? 0.0)
        }) { (_) in
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tabBarController?.tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
        }) { (_) in
        }
    }
}
```

How to use: -

```
var lastTabBarFrame: CGRect?

self.lastTabBarFrame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame

hideTabbar(self.tabBarController, self.lastTabBarFrame, self.view)

showTabbar(self.tabBarController, self.lastTabBarFrame)
```